# Create a user who only has access to external volume for sftp

Tags: server, permissions, ssh, sftp

I need a user on my Ubuntu Server who has only access to an external volume. The user can't have sudo rights or access to any other location on the server, only the files on the volume. I saw a few questions about that, but none of the solutions did work for me.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! *none of the solutions did work for me.* - what did not work?

Comment: google for "sftp chroot"